# Ideal structure of group $C^*$-agebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, fourier-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact groups and $C_r^*(G)$ be a reduce group $C^*$-algebra.

$\ Question:$What is the ideal structure of reduce group  $C_r^*(G)$?

Comment: In general it will be very complicated. I assume you mean reduced group Cstar algebras of discrete groups, in which case these algebras can often be simple. Important examples to have in mind are: the group of integers ${\bf Z}$; and the free group on two generators $F_2$.

Comment: While your question is a natural one to start with, I have voted to close because in its current form the question seems too broad to get effective answers (as opposed to people just googling for titles of articles that sound like they're relevant). If you could produce a more focused question, perhaps telling us which groups you wish to study, then I think your question would be fine.

Comment: Thanks,Dear prof. Y.Choi: Hi, If G to be the group of integers $Z$ , then $C^*$($Z$)=C($T$) so because ideal structure  of C(X) characterized then it is trivial ! The conditions on the G in mind , is locally compact group or finite group or totally disconnected compactly generated locally compact groups?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is still too broad; please actually provide some examples of the kinds of groups you want. By examples, I mean concrete examples, of particular groups. Every theorem about a general kind of group implies a theorem aout a particular example; in my opinion, as a researcher, if you don't know any examples of those kinds of groups, you need to find them and learn about them

Comment: For instance, since it sounds like you are a newcomer to the world of group Cstar algebras, you should read about the fact that the reduced Cstar algebra of the free group on two generators is simple, as this will give you some flavour of why it is usually hard to deduce properties about the ideal structure of $C_r^*(\Gamma)$ from group-theoretic properties of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Or if $C_r^*({\bf Z})$ is too easy an example, how about $C_r^*(H_3({\bf Z}))$, where $H_3({\bf Z})$ is the 3-dimensional Heisenberg group over the integers? There was an old article (paywall access I'm afraid) of Anderson and Paschke which looked at this algebra and related objects: http://math.uh.edu/~hjm/vol15-1.html